# SSL certificate chain completion is disabled

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, rancher

I have installed K8S cluster via Rancher and it is up and running except:

[image]

Looking into the log, it says:

```
W0414 09:19:00.301391       9 flags.go:221] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
nginx version: openresty/1.15.8.1
W0414 09:19:00.305182       9 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0414 09:19:00.305528       9 main.go:183] Creating API client for https://10.43.0.1:443
I0414 09:19:00.313466       9 main.go:227] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.17 (v1.17.4) - git (clean) commit 8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea - platform linux/amd64
I0414 09:19:00.318605       9 main.go:91] Validated ingress-nginx/default-http-backend as the default backend.
I0414 09:19:00.604027       9 main.go:102] Created fake certificate with PemFileName: /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem
I0414 09:19:00.657480       9 nginx.go:274] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
I0414 09:19:00.692928       9 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"nginx-configuration", UID:"5d7200c0-88cc-4b9e-97a3-e28e2a529970", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"660", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/nginx-configuration
I0414 09:19:00.696624       9 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"udp-services", UID:"8d6491ff-b617-4b01-b318-d4afd66cdb1f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"662", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/udp-services
I0414 09:19:00.696864       9 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"tcp-services", UID:"4ded14e4-6669-49de-89e6-f15007751014", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"661", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/tcp-services
I0414 09:19:01.858339       9 nginx.go:318] Starting NGINX process
I0414 09:19:01.858724       9 leaderelection.go:235] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0414 09:19:01.859332       9 controller.go:133] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0414 09:19:01.862863       9 status.go:86] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-28k5x
E0414 09:19:01.912314       9 controller.go:145] Unexpected failure reloading the backend:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: exit status 1
nginx: the configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg115117149 syntax is ok
2020/04/14 09:19:01 [emerg] 41#41: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg115117149 test failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's less to do with the SSL cert chain warning, and much more to do with it not having permission to run on port 80. Either you need to run it as root, or increase the port to one above 1024 (8080 is quite common). Also, this is a very small amount of information to go off to try help answer this question.

Comment: I have installed the K8S cluster with Rancher on Debian 9, so one click and wait until is finished. But I think, Debian maybe not allowed to run some Nginx on port 80.

Comment: are you trying to deploy nginx on top of the k8s cluster? if yes then which deployment yaml of nginx you used

Comment: No, the Nginx deployment comes from Rancher installation. During the installation, Rancher tries to deploy Ngninx service and I do not have control on it.